# Detecting User Input on a Web Page (Event Handling for Keystrokes or Input)

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-handling

I'm creating a basic chrome extension that will send message reminders as a user types anywhere on a web page.
However, I'm not certain how to accomplish this, I've considered using `keyUp` and `keyDown` events but I've only been successful if the event is watching a particular field whereas the goal is to detect text on any field where a user can type.

```
let timer,
        timeoutVal = 1000; // time it takes to wait for user to stop typing in ms

const status = document.getElementById('status');
const typer = document.getElementById('typer');

typer.addEventListener('keypress', handleKeyPress);
typer.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);

// when user is pressing down on keys, clear the timeout
function handleKeyPress(e) {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
  status.innerHTML = 'Typing...';
}

// when the user has stopped pressing on keys, set the timeout
// if the user presses on keys before the timeout is reached, then this timeout is canceled
function handleKeyUp(e) {
    window.clearTimeout(timer); // prevent errant multiple timeouts from being generated
    timer = window.setTimeout(() => {
    status.innerHTML = 'Done';
  }, timeoutVal);
}
```

What is the best way to achieve the expected result?

Keep in mind, I'm trying to have this chrome extension trigger ANY time a user is typing text on a web page OR any time a user clicks inside of a text field to begin typing.

The chrome extension should only disappear if a user has no text in a text field and the text field is not active (otherwise if there is text in the text field, leave the extension up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add the event listener to the html element:

```
document.querySelector('html').addEventListener('keypress', () => {
  console.log('asd')
});
```

Another option is to loop through all of the fields that the user can type in:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(inp => {
  inp.addEventListener('keypress', () => {console.log('asd')})
});
```